# How to prevent the logging of a failed request to favorite.ico with ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

This will be the 5th such question that centers around the favorite.ico and ServiceStack webservice framework. I understand the rationale behind logging resource not found, and most of the workarounds use the built-in not found handler e.g.

```
appHost.CatchAllHandlers.Add((httpMethod, pathInfo, filePath) => {
   if (pathInfo.StartsWith("favicon"))
      return new NotFoundHttpHandler();
});
```

but this still logs an exception to the logging infrastructure. Is there a way to get the best of both worlds, log when a resource was not found while NOT logging the request for the favorite.ico. Do I have to write code? code scares me :)

Thank you,
Stephen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Logging is in the [NotFoundHttpHandler](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Host/Handlers/NotFoundHttpHandler.cs) itself so to avoid logging you'd return a custom HttpHandler that doesn't log, e.g:

```
appHost.CatchAllHandlers.Add((httpMethod, pathInfo, filePath) => {
   if (pathInfo.StartsWith("/favicon"))
      return new CustomActionHandler((req,res) => {
          res.StatusCode = 404;
          res.StatusDescription = "Favicon not found";
          res.EndRequest();
      });
   return null;
});
```

Comment: Returning null instead of the NotFoundHttpHandler won't prevent all other unknow resources from being logged, right?

Comment: @Stephen returning `null` is essentially a NoOp, where the request continues as normal.

Comment: mythz - Understood, we're talking about per request, in which case this makes perfect sense.